# Google Chrome - Screen capture failing when iframe is used, same script works without iframe

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension, webrtc

When i use this following script it works with normal browser. But when iframe is used then its showing me this error:

Does anyone know what is causing this and can be resolved?

ERROR:

```
channel message Object {type: "getScreenPending", id: 24504, request: 6} content.js:4
channel message Object {type: "gotScreen", id: 24504, request: 6} content.js:4
>>> ShareScreen: if any err NavigatorUserMediaError {constraintName: "", message: "", name: "InvalidStateError"} test.js:1616
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Screen sharing",
  "description": "Screensharing utility",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "minimum_chrome_version": "34",
  "icons": {
    "48" : "icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "desktopCapture"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [ {
    "js": [ "content.js" ],
    "all_frames": true,
    "run_at": "document_start",
    "matches": ["*://*.a.com/*", "*://*.b.com/*"]
  }],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
        "icon.png"
  ]
}
```

background.js:

```
/* background page, responsible for actually choosing media */
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (channel) {
    channel.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
        switch(message.type) {
        case 'getScreen':
            var pending = chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(message.options || ['screen', 'window'], 
                                                                   channel.sender.tab, function (streamid) {
                // communicate this string to the app so it can call getUserMedia with it
                message.type = 'gotScreen';
                message.sourceId = streamid;
                channel.postMessage(message);
            });
            // let the app know that it can cancel the timeout
            message.type = 'getScreenPending';
            message.request = pending;
            channel.postMessage(message);
            break;
        case 'cancelGetScreen':
            chrome.desktopCapture.cancelChooseDesktopMedia(message.request);
            message.type = 'canceledGetScreen';
            channel.postMessage(message);
            break;
        }
    });
});
```

content.js:

```
/* the chrome content script which can listen to the page dom events */
var channel = chrome.runtime.connect();
channel.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
    console.log('channel message', message);
    window.postMessage(message, '*');
});

window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    if (event.source != window)
        return;
    if (!event.data && (event.data.type == 'getScreen' || event.data.type == 'cancelGetScreen'))
        return;
    channel.postMessage(event.data);
});
```

Comment: when i run the iframe from same subdomain https://subdomain.maindomain.com/test.php (iframe src=https://subdomain.maindomain.com/core.php) then it works. But when i am running it as https://www.maindomain.com/otherpages (iframe src=https://subdomain.maindomain.com/core.php) then this is not working. Very confusing.

Comment: Could you edit your question and include that information? That kind of information is very relevant to your question. And which version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: @Rob W: i was wrong my answer is not correct. Today i was testing again and its still throwing the same error.

Comment: I'm willing to look into your issue if you create a demo page where the problem in your question can be verified. Don't forget to mention which version of Chrome and which OS you're using.

Comment: OK - i will prepare that link (if you do not mind, is there any way confidentially i can send this link to you like private or so? because for the company i am working i had NDA signed as temporary task). Google Chrome M38 and Canary latest with Windows 7, 8.1 64-bit and OSX 10.9.4 its happening, also with Linux Ubuntu 12.04, 14.04 64-bit same issue. Thank you very much.

Comment: See my profile for contact details.

Comment: @RobW: i sent you an email today. Please let me know. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that the a stream can only be used by frames whose URL match the origin of the tab. Starting with Chrome 40, you can use the stream in frames as well if you set `tab.url` to a URL whose origin matches the frame ([crbug.com/425344](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=425344)).

The stream is only valid for ten seconds, so you have to follow the following flow:

1. Load the iframe that contains the page that should handle the stream. This page **must** be served from a secure scheme, e.g. `https:` or `chrome-extension:`.
2. Send the frame's origin (`location.origin`) to the background page.
3. Request the desktop stream using the tab info, with `tab.url` set to the frame's URL or origin.
4. Send the streamId back to the frame and use it (within ten seconds).

Example (based on the code in the question):

```js
var tab = channel.sender.tab;
// NEW (Chrome 40+)
tab.url = message.url; // Your custom message, e.g. {url: location.origin}
chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(['screen', 'window'], tab,
    function (streamid) {
        // ... see question for the rest of the code
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - this is not a code problem, browser problem

2 - this is not working because i am launching the extension from HTTP (http://www.maindomain.com) using iframe a HTTPS (https://subdomain.maindomain.com) link which is using the browser extension

So to fix it. I needed to use HTTPS (https://www.maindomain.com) opening HTTPS iframe links (https://subdomain.maindomain.com) . Since then it works now.

Hope this help others.

NOTE: problem occurred: when i run the iframe from same subdomain subdomain.maindomain.com/test.php (iframe src=subdomain.maindomain.com/core.php) then it works. But when i am running it as maindomain.com/otherpages (iframe src=subdomain.maindomain.com/core.php) then this is not working. Was very confusing.

EDIT: This still did not resolved the problem. screen share dialog box opens but when i press share screen then it gives same error and fails.