# In chrome extensions, is there a way to record screen without ssl?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, google-chrome-extension, compression, screencast

I'm not sure if this is possible but is there a way to capture screen using an extension without an https url and without going into native code? Does chrome provide some kind of API call for capturing screen with a compression codec that doesn't involve `chrome.desktopCapture`?

I'm also wondering how something like screencastify works, where does one begin with trying to build something like this?

Comment: Even with SSL, you cannot record the screen without the `chrome.desktopCapture` API.

Comment: so is there prehaps some way to use chrome.desktopCapture without ssl?

Comment: Did you understand my comment? SSL is not relevant, you need a Chrome extension before the [`chrome.desktopCapture` extension API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture) can be used...

Comment: yes i know that, im coding the extension, but the api can only be called on https pages, is there a way around this? even if only for testing purposes on localhost, i dont want to get a ssl certificate just to explore the api

Comment: `chrome-extension:` URLs are viewed as secure, so you can also load the extension in an iframe which in turn displays the video, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/26424366.

Comment: thanks rob, i did end up getting an ssl certificate installed on my website to test my custom code since it just saves a lot of hassle, but thanks for this suggestion, i never thought of doing it through an iframe I'll keep this in mind next time!