# Record user actions in Chrome Devtools: Possible?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm looking for a way to record every thing I do in Chrome Devtools so I can play it back verbatim. I've seen a lot of docs on how to manipulate page content, track page performance and behavior etc from devtools extensions, but nothing yet about actually watching what I do in Chrome Devtools itself. I'd be willing to write an extension if that's what needed. The goal is a teaching tool where I can record things I'm doing in devtools and play them back. (Of course, one could use a GIF recorder but that's so 00's). Something I've looked a little bit at so far is [chrome devtools protocol viewer](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/#extension) but not sure if it could accomplish the task.

Can anybody suggest a potential way to accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Need examples, question as it is is quite unclear. Does the 2022 ans fit your  (unclear) use case perfectly?

Answer (score 3):

Now Chrome has an inbuilt recorder tool available in the Dev Tools. Much better than installing any 3rd party extension. Additionally, there are many more features to track the user journey.

[Recorder in Chrome Dev Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/recorder/)

Answer (score 0):

You may try using [Desktop Capture API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture) which can  be used to capture content of screen, individual windows or tabs. Here's a [demo app](https://github.com/wpp/ScreenStream) that shows you how to use a Chrome extension to access the desktopCapture API in your web-application. Additional reference which might help: [In chrome extensions, is there a way to record screen without ssl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29035215/in-chrome-extensions-is-there-a-way-to-record-screen-without-ssl)